# Excel formula to split a cell and reverses the order

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

An example source cell would be something like:

```
Some:Thing:random:here
```

I want to transform it to this (reversing the order of each group):

```
here:random:Thing:Some
```

I would prefer a formula, without using macros, if possible.

This is the formula I've been trying to manipulate to change the last part of an IP.

> =IF(C12="","",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(C12,".","."&REPT("",LEN(C12))),LEN(C12)*2)&MID(SUBSTITUTE(C12,".","."&REPT("> ",LEN(C12))),LEN(C12)*2,LEN(C12))&"5"," ",""))

Comment: I've been trying to manipulate a formula that I use to change the last part of an IP.  =IF(C12="","",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(C12,".","."&REPT(" ",LEN(C12))),LEN(C12)*2)&MID(SUBSTITUTE(C12,".","."&REPT(" ",LEN(C12))),LEN(C12)*2,LEN(C12))&"5"," ",""))

Comment: The commas wont be in a set location would they? Wo;; there always be three columns?

Comment: Why are you avoiding macros? This can be cleanly solved with a small User-Defined Function.

Comment: There will prob. always be 3 ".", so 4 parts of data (although the last part could have extra stuff after it).  In a perfect world, I would like it to be dynamic, but I'd be more than happy with the 4 parts (3 separators).  The length of each "part" will vary some...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming three colons as separators try this formula

`=IF(C12="","",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C12,":",REPT(" ",100)),300,100))&":"&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C12,":",REPT(" ",100)),200,100))&":"&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C12,":",REPT(" ",100)),100,100))&":"&LEFT(C12,FIND(":",C12)-1))`

**Explanation:**

To get the part after the last colon I used this formula:

`=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C12,":",REPT(" ",100)),300,100))`

That uses `SUBSTITUTE` to replace each colon with 100 spaces. As we are dealing with IP addresses each part is clearly a small number of characters so then using `MID` to take 100 characters starting at char 300 will include only the last part of the IP address and some spaces - `TRIM` then trims the spaces - I used the same approach to get the middle two parts and then `LEFT` function combined with `FIND` to get the first part

Comment: This is kinda brilliant. It took me a bit to parse it. Any chance you'd explain what you're doing?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is an IP address 1.2.3.4

```
dim astring as string
dim splat() as variant

astring = "1.2.3.4"
splat =split(string,".")
string=splat(3)&"."& splat(2)&"."& splat(1)&"."&splat(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, there may be a way to solve this without using VBA, but here is a user-defined formula you can use to do exactly what you're asking for, as well as handle different delimiters:

```
Function ReverseList(InputString As String, Optional DelimiterString As String) As String

' Provide a default value of "," as the delimiter.
If Len(DelimiterString) = 0 Then
    LabelString = ","
End If

' The InputArray() will contain the values, separated at the delimiter string.
Dim InputArray() As String
InputArray() = Split(InputString, DelimiterString)

' The OutputArray() will contain the values in reverse order.
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
j = UBound(InputArray)
Dim OutputArray() As String
ReDim OutputArray(0 To j) As String

For i = 0 To j
    OutputArray(i) = InputArray(j - i)
Next i

' Now we put the reversed list back together, adding the delimiter back in.
ReverseList = Join(OutputArray(), DelimiterString)

End Function
```

You can call this in a cell with `=ReverseList(A1, ":")` in order to handle your example.

While it's scary to create your first UDF, it's pretty straightforward if you [follow the steps](http://www.exceldigest.com/myblog/2011/04/23/how-to-create-a-user-defined-function-in-excel-2007-or-excel-2010/).

Comment: Dealing with the scripting in newer versions of Excel require the different file extension as well as permission settings.  If this were just for me, I might be more apt to go this route.  I REALLY appreciate your link though as I've tried using VBA, but couldn't get them to work (I forgot to create a module), so thank you soooo much for that link!  Definitely keeping your script in mind in case I need it for something more complex!

Comment: Creating a module is the secret step everyone needs to know about.